# KEYCLOAK - Extending OIDC Protocol | Missing Credentials Tab | Add extra claims in AccessTokenResponse

Tags: keycloak, redhat-sso

We are trying to implement SMART On FHIR healthcare authorization protocol specification. This spec is an extension to OIDC (open id connect protocol). In SMART on FHIR, we need to add extra claims called 'patient' with value say '123' in AccessTokenResponse object during the OAUTH dance.

In order to accomplish this, I tried to extended the OIDCLoginProtocol and OIDCLoginProtocolFactory classes and given a new name to this protocol called 'smart-openid-connect'. I created this as a SPI (service provider interface) JAR and copied it to /standalone/deployments folder. Now, I can see the new protocol called 'smart-openid-connect' in the UI, but it does not show Access Type options in the client creation screen to select as a confidential client. Hence, I am not able to create client secrets as the Credentials menu is not appearing for this new protocol.

I have the following questions:

How to enable the Credentials tab in the client creation screen using SPI for the new protocol that I created.?
Which class I need to override to add extra claims in AccessTokenResponse ?
Kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: We are using KEYCLOAK as the authorization server to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your steps for developing our custom protocol. When we migrate our company existed authentication protocol, I have used org.keycloak.adapters.authentication.ClientCredentialsProvider, org.keycloak.authentication.ClientAuthenticatorFactory, org.keycloak.authentication.ClientAuthenticator classes for defining our custom protocol. Credentials tab is only visible if oidc and confidential choices are selected. It is defined on UI javascript codes. So we choose oidc option for setting custom protocol. Afterwards, we return back to our custom protocol.

XyzClientAuthenticatorFactory

```java
public class XyzClientAuthenticatorFactory implements ClientAuthenticatorFactory, ClientAuthenticator {
    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "xyz-client-authenticator";
    public static final String DISPLAY_TEXT = "Xyz Client Authenticator";
    public static final String REFERENCE_CATEGORY = null;
    public static final String HELP_TEXT = null;

    private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<ProviderConfigProperty>();

    private AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] REQUIREMENT_CHOICES = {
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.REQUIRED,
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.ALTERNATIVE,
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.DISABLED};

    static {
        ProviderConfigProperty property;

        property = new ProviderConfigProperty();
        property.setName(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_ID);
        property.setLabel("Xyz App Id");
        property.setType(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE);
        configProperties.add(property);

        property = new ProviderConfigProperty();
        property.setName(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_KEY);
        property.setLabel("Xyz App Key");
        property.setType(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE);
        configProperties.add(property);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticateClient(ClientAuthenticationFlowContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return DISPLAY_TEXT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getReferenceCategory() {
        return REFERENCE_CATEGORY;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthenticator create() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConfigurable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
        return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserSetupAllowed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigPropertiesPerClient() {
        return configProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAdapterConfiguration(ClientModel client) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_ID, client.getAttribute(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_ID));
        result.put(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_KEY, client.getAttribute(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_KEY));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getProtocolAuthenticatorMethods(String loginProtocol) {
        if (loginProtocol.equals(OIDCLoginProtocol.LOGIN_PROTOCOL)) {
            Set<String> results = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            results.add(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_ID);
            results.add(Constants.CLIENT_SETTINGS_APP_KEY);
            return results;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return HELP_TEXT;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }
}
```

XyzClientCredential

```java
public class XyzClientCredential implements ClientCredentialsProvider {
    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "xyz-client-credential";

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(KeycloakDeployment deployment, Object config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setClientCredentials(KeycloakDeployment deployment, Map<String, String> requestHeaders, Map<String, String> formParams) {

    }
}
```

XyzLoginProtocolFactory

```java
public class XyzLoginProtocolFactory implements LoginProtocolFactory {

    static {

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ProtocolMapperModel> getBuiltinMappers() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Object createProtocolEndpoint(RealmModel realm, EventBuilder event) {
        return new XyzLoginProtocolService(realm, event);
    }

    protected void addDefaultClientScopes(RealmModel realm, ClientModel newClient) {
        addDefaultClientScopes(realm, Arrays.asList(newClient));
    }

    protected void addDefaultClientScopes(RealmModel realm, List<ClientModel> newClients) {
        Set<ClientScopeModel> defaultClientScopes = realm.getDefaultClientScopes(true).stream()
                .filter(clientScope -> getId().equals(clientScope.getProtocol()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for (ClientModel newClient : newClients) {
            for (ClientScopeModel defaultClientScopeModel : defaultClientScopes) {
                newClient.addClientScope(defaultClientScopeModel, true);
            }
        }

        Set<ClientScopeModel> nonDefaultClientScopes = realm.getDefaultClientScopes(false).stream()
                .filter(clientScope -> getId().equals(clientScope.getProtocol()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for (ClientModel newClient : newClients) {
            for (ClientScopeModel nonDefaultClientScope : nonDefaultClientScopes) {
                newClient.addClientScope(nonDefaultClientScope, true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void createDefaultClientScopes(RealmModel newRealm, boolean addScopesToExistingClients) {
        // Create default client scopes for realm built-in clients too
        if (addScopesToExistingClients) {
            addDefaultClientScopes(newRealm, newRealm.getClients());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setupClientDefaults(ClientRepresentation rep, ClientModel newClient) {

    }

    @Override
    public LoginProtocol create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new XyzLoginProtocol().setSession(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
        log.infof("XyzLoginProtocolFactory init");
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
        factory.register(event -> {
            if (event instanceof RealmModel.ClientCreationEvent) {
                ClientModel client = ((RealmModel.ClientCreationEvent)event).getCreatedClient();
                addDefaultClientScopes(client.getRealm(), client);
                addDefaults(client);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void addDefaults(ClientModel client) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return XyzLoginProtocol.LOGIN_PROTOCOL;
    }
}
```

XyzLoginProtocol

```java
public class XyzLoginProtocol implements LoginProtocol {
    public static final String LOGIN_PROTOCOL = "xyz";

    protected KeycloakSession session;

    protected RealmModel realm;

    protected UriInfo uriInfo;

    protected HttpHeaders headers;

    protected EventBuilder event;

    public XyzLoginProtocol(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, UriInfo uriInfo, HttpHeaders headers, EventBuilder event) {
        this.session = session;
        this.realm = realm;
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.event = event;
    }

    public XyzLoginProtocol() {

    }

    @Override
    public XyzLoginProtocol setSession(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public XyzLoginProtocol setRealm(RealmModel realm) {
        this.realm = realm;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public XyzLoginProtocol setUriInfo(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public XyzLoginProtocol setHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public XyzLoginProtocol setEventBuilder(EventBuilder event) {
        this.event = event;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Response authenticated(AuthenticationSessionModel authSession, UserSessionModel userSession, ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx) {
        log.debugf("Authenticated.. User: %s, Session Id: %s", userSession.getUser().getUsername(), userSession.getId());
        try {
            ....
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO handle TokenNotFoundException exception
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Response sendError(AuthenticationSessionModel authSession, Error error) {
        new AuthenticationSessionManager(session).removeAuthenticationSession(realm, authSession, true);

        String redirect = authSession.getRedirectUri();
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(redirect);
            return Response.status(302).location(uri).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void backchannelLogout(UserSessionModel userSession, AuthenticatedClientSessionModel clientSession) {
        ClientModel client = clientSession.getClient();
        new ResourceAdminManager(session).logoutClientSession(realm, client, clientSession);
    }

    @Override
    public Response frontchannelLogout(UserSessionModel userSession, AuthenticatedClientSessionModel clientSession) {
        throw new RuntimeException("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    @Override
    public Response finishLogout(UserSessionModel userSession) {
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requireReauthentication(UserSessionModel userSession, AuthenticationSessionModel authSession) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendPushRevocationPolicyRequest(RealmModel realm, ClientModel resource, int notBefore, String managementUrl) {
        PushNotBeforeAction adminAction = new PushNotBeforeAction(TokenIdGenerator.generateId(), Time.currentTime() + 30, resource.getClientId(), notBefore);
        String token = session.tokens().encode(adminAction);
        log.tracev("pushRevocation resource: {0} url: {1}", resource.getClientId(), managementUrl);
        URI target = UriBuilder.fromUri(managementUrl).path(AdapterConstants.K_PUSH_NOT_BEFORE).build();
        try {
            int status = session.getProvider(HttpClientProvider.class).postText(target.toString(), token);
            boolean success = status == 204 || status == 200;
            log.tracef("pushRevocation success for %s: %s", managementUrl, success);
            return success;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ServicesLogger.LOGGER.failedToSendRevocation(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

XyzLoginProtocolService

```java
public class XyzLoginProtocolService {
    private final RealmModel realm;
    private final EventBuilder event;

    @Context
    private KeycloakSession session;

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    @Context
    private HttpRequest request;

    @Context
    private ClientConnection clientConnection;

    public XyzLoginProtocolService(RealmModel realm, EventBuilder event) {
        this.realm = realm;
        this.event = event;
        this.event.realm(realm);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("request")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @NoCache
    public Response request(ApipmLoginRequest loginRequest) {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the code Ismail. My requirement is to have a new protocol name say 'smart-open-id" which would have similar functionality as OIDC along with ability to create confidential clients and to have a custom access token response fields. So, from what you are saying, I understand that I can achieve it only by modifying the Java script code to enable Credentials tab for this new protocol. Am I reading your answer correctly?

Comment: Yes, you should edit html template code. The template file is kc-tabs-client.html, you can easily find by searching for credentials or oidc words.